# Matlab symbolic function susbstitution

Tags: matlab, function, substitution, symbolic-math

I am defining a symbolic function

```
syms x(n);
x(n) = (n==0);
n=-1:1;
```

When I try `x(n)+x(n-1)`
I get

```
 [ -1 == 0, 0 == 0, 1 == 0]
+[ -2 == 0, -1 == 0, 0 == 0]
=[ -3 == 0, -1 == 0, 1 == 0]
```

I want to force the symbolic function to substitute the values so I get the following results instead.

```
 [ 0, 1, 0]
+[ 0, 0, 1]
=[ 0, 1, 1]
```

I tried something like `x(n) = logical(n==0);` and `x(n) = double(n==0);` but I got the same result.
I know that `double(x(n))+double(x(n-1))` works, but I want to use `x(n)` directly and do the substitution in the definition of the symbolic function.
Can this be done?

Comment: It appears that Mupad will refuse to add booleans, even if you try to force it: `evalin(symengine,'TRUE+TRUE')` throws Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `piecewise` is the only way to cast a boolean to an integer in Mupad. Unfortunately, it only available in Mupad itself, so you have to use `evalin` to get it:

```
syms asinteger(fun) x(n)
asinteger(fun) = evalin(symengine,'piecewise([fun,1],[Otherwise,0])');
x(n) = asinteger(n==0);
n=-1:1;

>> x(n)+x(n-1)

ans =

[ 0, 1, 1]
```

Think of the `asinteger` function as the symbolic version of `double` or `int64`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do is to use [`isAlways`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html), which evaluates if an expression (equality or inequality) is true:

```
syms x(n);
x(n) = (n==0);
m = -1:1; % Use a different variable to not overwrite symbolic n
isAlways(x(m))+isAlways(x(m-1))
```

Or you can use an anonymous function to avoid multiple calls to `isAlways`:

```
m = -1:1;
x = @(n)isAlways(sym(n)==0);
x(m)+x(m-1)
```

Both of these return an array of doubles (`[0 1 1]`). You can use [`logical`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html) to convert this to a logical array. You might also find [`sym/isequaln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isequaln.html) useful in some cases.